# PayPal payment issue for orders with decimal quantity

Tags: paypal

We are using paypal payment method in our website. We have integrated the form post option for paypal payment process. 
If quantity with integer value is given the process is working fine without any hustle.
Recently we have updated the quantity to decimal which is needed for our business process. 
But quantity with decimal values(10.5) is given the request returns bad input error.

Please find the screenshot.

[image]